# How to model a polymorphic list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to model some polymorphic-type data in haskell. I understand why the following code doesn't work, but I'm hoping it illustrates what I'm trying to do. My question is: what is an idiomatic way to model this with Haskell? (You don't need to keep the input format the same if there is a better way - I don't have any existing code or data.)

```
data Running = Sprint | Jog deriving (Show)
data Lifting = Barbell | Dumbbell deriving (Show)

data Time   = Time   Integer deriving (Show)
data Pounds = Pounds Integer deriving (Show)

data TimedActivity    = TimedActivity Running Time deriving (Show)
data WeightedActivity = WeightedActivity Lifting Pounds deriving (Show)

class Activity a

instance Activity TimedActivity
instance Activity WeightedActivity

-- I have a list of activities
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show [ TimedActivity Sprint (Time 10)
                       , WeightedActivity Barbell (Pounds 100)
                       ]

-- I then want to apply functions to generate summaries and
-- reports from those activities, i.e.:
extractLifts :: (Activity x) => [x] -> [WeightedActivity]
extractTimes :: (Activity x) => [x] -> [TimedActivity]
```

Comment: The first reason why it doesn't work is because you're missing a few `where`s at the end of `class Activity a` and both `instance Activity` lines.  But I'm working on a real answer right now.

Answer (score 8):

For your specific example, you can use an `Either` to unify both types within the same list:

```
both :: [Either TimedActivity WeightedActivity]
both = [ Left $ TimedActivity Sprint (Time 10)
       , Right $ WeightedActivity Barbell (Pounds 100)
       ]

extractLifts :: [Either TimedActivity WeightedActivity] -> [WeightedActivity]
extractLifts = rights

extractTimes :: [Either TimedActivity WeightedActivity] -> [TimedActivity]
extractTimes = lefts
```

For more than two types, just define your own abstract data type to unify them:

```
data Multiple = Case1 Type1 | Case2 Type2 | ...
```

... and extraction functions like so:

```
extractCase1 :: [Multiple] -> [Type1]
extractCase1 ms = [t1 | Case1 t1 <- ms]
```

Comment: This solution do not scale well. Your "Activity API" should known all "uptypes" "a priori". Really it "is not" a polymorphic list (is a unique type with a cross product of types). (I'm waiting your book! ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I want regardless, since I only have a small number of a priori types I care about. Will have a play over the weekend to make sure.

Comment: @josejuan I'm solving the text of the problem, not the title.  :)  I will begin working on my book after I complete my PhD.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that if you want polymorphic lists, use Python.

The long answer is that Haskell is intentionally designed *not* to do this.  There are ways of having fully polymorphic "lists", but they are difficult to work with and more inefficient.  You wouldn't be able to use normal list methods on them, since they wouldn't be of the `[a]` type.  If you want to combine two data types, the `Either` type is very convenient and has a lot of built-in functions, but the more types you add, the more inconvenient your type signatures are going to become.  A good rule of thumb is if you're trying to build polymorphic lists, you're doing something wrong.  Haskell has good ways of encapsulating types with algebraic data types.

The problem with this particular code is that while both `WeightedActivity` and `TimedActivity` are instances of `Activity`, the list still has to consist of a single instance of `Activity`.  A list of type `Activity a => [a]` is not saying that you can mix different activities, but rather that all of the members of the list, which are all `Activity`s, are the *same type* of `Activity`.  You can't have a list of `Int`s and `Doubles`, because they're different types, even though they both have `Num` instances.

Instead, you could combine `TimedActivity`, `WeightedActivity`, and `Activity` into a single data type as

```hs
data Activity
    = TimedActivity Running Time
    | WeightedActivity Lifting Pounds
    deriving (Show)
```

And then if you have new activities to add, you can simply add them to the `Activity` data type.  Then your `extract` functions are really easy to write with pattern matching.

Comment: `The short answer is that if you want polymorphic lists, use Python` ... are you serious ;)

Comment: @Ankur Totally serious.  I have never had a need to have truly polymorphic lists in Haskell.  Besides, what's the point?  Sure, you can use existentials to do this, but what you're really doing is making a type that wraps other types, it's not truly polymorphic.  There are only a handful of cases _ever_ that really need them, so I consider it code smell if you're trying to solve a problem with them.

Comment: @bheklilr: Like all things, existential types have their place. If you use them as a substitute for OO-style heterogeneous collections, maybe that’s not ideal. But for example, at work we have a library that needs to centrally cache the results of requests to various (heterogeneous) data sources—for that, existential types are exactly the right thing.

Comment: @bheklilr: Using `Dynamic` will be almost same as Python approach. Apart from that lets not start an answer with `You should/can do that in xyz` when someone is trying to learn Haskell or for that matter learning anything new.

Comment: As far as definitions are concerned, I think you are using "polymorphic" when you ought to say "heterogenous". The standard list in Haskell is perfectly polymorphic, it can be `[Int]` or `[Char]` for example.

Comment: @JonPurdy In your case, I would say that needing heterogenous (thanks Mike Hartl for the vocabulary lesson, this is why I shouldn't post late at night) lists is acceptable, but in cases like OP mentioned, it isn't.

Comment: @Ankur My answer could easily have been Ruby, Javascript, or any other language that is designed to let you do that.  The point was that if you think you need heterogeneous lists, you should really revisit your problem first.  If you truly can't find a different solution, then press ahead with them, but the cases where it's necessary are few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

`extractLifts :: (Activity x) => [x] -> [WeightedActivity]`

This line says you are trying to build a function that can match a type of individual elements of a list (possibly filter our other types). I don't think you can do that without going hacky.

(I suppose, that line was meant to be `extractLifts :: [(Activity x) => x] -> [WeightedActivity]` - the subtle difference is that your version "picks the type x" once for the whole list, so all elements in the list are of the same type, same instance of Activity, whereas the second version will pick the type for each element individually)

Comment: That not only needs a language extension, but doesn't work either.

Comment: I didn't mean it's going to work, I only pointed out the meaning of the signature is probably even more generic.